# Accessing data in a nested structure using pointers

Tags: c, scanf, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am doing an assignment which requires me to write a code that contains a nested structure. The problem is actually pretty simple. Just to obtain coordinates of the corners of a rectangle. I have been researching online but most examples are without the typedef structure. My problem is mainly being unsure of what is the correct syntax to access and store the data. I have the structure templates as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point; // Create a Point datatype;
```

```
typedef struct // nested structure
{
    Point topLeft; // topLeft is the variable name for "Point" structure with x&y property
    Point botRight; // botRight is the variable name for "Point" structure with x&y property
} Rectangle; // Create a Rectangle datatype with Point structure within
```

```
void getRect(Rectangle *r); // function prototype
int main()
{
Rectangle r; // initializing rectangle;
getRect(&r); // call function to get inputs using call by reference
}

void getRect(Rectangle *r)
{
    printf("Enter top left points:\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", r->topLeft.x,r->topLeft.y); // Not sure if this is correct as my program can compile and run up till this point and crashes.
    printf("Enter bottom right points:\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", r->botRight.x,r->botRight.y);
}
```

Seeking everyone's kind guidance on this matter!

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments of the calls of scanf shall be pointers. For example

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &r->topLeft.x, &r->topLeft.y);
```

and

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &r->botRight.x, &r->botRight.y);
```

That is you need to pass objects x and y by reference that the function scanf could deal with the original objects instead of copies of their values.

In C passing by reference means passing objects indirectly through pointers to them. In this case the called function can get a direct access to the objects by using the dereferencing operation of the pointers.

Comment: Hello Vlad, Thank you so much for your kind input. It has resolved my issue. A simple yet amazing learning point for me. I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` does not allocate memory so you have always to pass addresses where the function can place the data for each specifier, those things like `%d` or `%lf`. So in your case you must pass the address of each `double` field using, well, the address of operator, `&`

**Always** test the return of `scanf()`. There is no reason to continue on reading data if you could not get one of the points

Avoiid this type of comment:

```
    void getRect(Rectangle *r); // function prototype
```

Is is fairly obvious that this is a prototype. There a few of these comments in your code. Prefer to use comments that describe uses, parameters, arguments, algorithms...

#### an example

The small program below declares your structures in some usual ways, including a function to return a `Rectangle` for each call and one to print the data out. It is usual for testing. It is just an example. I am not telling it is good or best or anything.

**for the SO Police**: I always cast the pointer to `malloc()` because, well, I do.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;

}   Point;


typedef struct
{
    Point tL; // top left
    Point bR; // bottom right

}   Rectangle;

Rectangle*  rFactory();
int         showR(Rectangle*);

int         main(void)
{
    Point   A = { 2., 3. };

    Point   B = 
    {
        .y = 3.4,
        .x = 0.
    };

    Point*  pP = &A;
    printf( "Point is (%lf,%lf)\n", pP->x, pP->y ); // using pointer
    printf( "Point is (%lf,%lf)\n", A.x, A.y ); // using data directly

    Rectangle   R0 = { A,B };

    Rectangle   R1 =
    {
        {
            .x = 0.,
            .y = 2.
        },  // tL

        {  3.,4. } // bR
    };

    Rectangle   R2 = 
    {
        .bR = { 1.,2. },
        .tL = { -4.,-5 }
    };

    Rectangle*  pR = &R0;
    pR = &R1;
    pR = &R2; // :) just to get rid of the unused-var warnings 
    printf( "(via pointer) Rectangle is [(%lf,%lf), (%lf,%lf)]\n",
        pR->tL.x, pR->tL.y,
        pR->bR.x, pR->bR.y ); // using pointer
    printf( "(via data) Rectangle is [(%lf,%lf), (%lf,%lf)]\n",
        R2.tL.x, R2.tL.y,
        R2.bR.x, R2.bR.y ); // using data directly

    R2.bR.x = 0.;
    R2.bR.y = 0.;
    printf( "(Changed bR) Rectangle is [(%lf,%lf), (%lf,%lf)]\n",
        pR->tL.x, pR->tL.y,
        pR->bR.x, pR->bR.y ); // using pointer

    printf( "(Using function)\n\n");
    showR( &R2);

    // using a 'factory function gets a new one
    printf( "\n\n(Using factory function)\n\n");
    Rectangle*  other = rFactory();
    showR( other );
    free(other); // this one was allocated

    return 0;

}


Rectangle*  rFactory()
{
    Rectangle* one = (Rectangle*) malloc(sizeof(Rectangle));
    if ( one == NULL ) return NULL; // could not alloc
    int res = 0;

    printf("\
\tEnter points like '3., -2.3' separated by at least one space\
\n\tTop Left point: ");
    res = scanf("%lf %lf", &one->tL.x,&one->tL.y);
    if ( res != 2 )
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    };  // if()

    printf("\
\n\tBottom Right point: ");
    res = scanf("%lf %lf", &one->bR.x,&one->bR.y);
    if ( res != 2 )
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    };  // if()
    
    return one;
};


int     showR( Rectangle* pR)
{
    if ( pR == NULL ) return -1;
    printf( "\n\t[using showR()] Rectangle is [(%lf,%lf), (%lf,%lf)]\n",
        pR->tL.x, pR->tL.y,
        pR->bR.x, pR->bR.y ); // using pointer
    return 0;
}
```

#### the output

```
PS C:\src\bases> gcc -o tst -std=c17 -Wall sh.c
PS C:\src\bases> ./tst
Point is (2.000000,3.000000)
Point is (2.000000,3.000000)
(via pointer) Rectangle is [(-4.000000,-5.000000), (1.000000,2.000000)]
(via data) Rectangle is [(-4.000000,-5.000000), (1.000000,2.000000)]
(Changed bR) Rectangle is [(-4.000000,-5.000000), (0.000000,0.000000)]
(Using function)


        [using showR()] Rectangle is [(-4.000000,-5.000000), (0.000000,0.000000)]


(Using factory function)

        Enter points like '3., -2.3' separated by at least one space
        Top Left point: 1. 2.

        Bottom Right point: 3. 4.

        [using showR()] Rectangle is [(1.000000,2.000000), (3.000000,4.000000)]
PS C:\src\bases>
```

Comment: Hello @arfneto. Thank you for taking the time for such in-depth explanation. Advice well taken for the usage of comments, will definitely place more meaningful comments in the future! A very interesting alternate perspective on how the code could be written. I never would have written it this way as I am still a beginner. Will take the time to analyze and understand the in-depth code you've written. Appreciate it sir.

Comment: Welcome you are

Comment: Note that half of the code above just shows how to declare, initialize and copy structures. It is not useful and is doing nothing. It is just a kit of examples.

Comment: The lines `Rectangle*  other = rFactory();` and `showR( other );` and `free(other);`. by the other side, are a very common and powerful construct in programming, `factory functions` that return a pointer to a newly created something, a function to dump its contents during testing, and the free-ing of the area. Sure, in practice it is not common to be in 3 consecutive lines